# field integrity exception error while saving lightning component

Tags: lightning-design-system

I copied the following code from SLDS into my component and tried to save it.... showing the following error

```
<aura:component>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="file-selector-primary-label">Attachment</span>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-file-selector slds-file-selector_files">
                <div class="slds-file-selector__dropzone">
                    <input type="file" class="slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text" accept="image/png" id="file-upload-input-01" aria-labelledby="file-selector-primary-label file-selector-secondary-label" />
                    <label class="slds-file-selector__body" for="file-upload-input-01" id="file-selector-secondary-label">
                        <span class="slds-file-selector__button slds-button slds-button_neutral">
                            <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
                                <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#upload" />
                            </svg>
                            Upload Files
                        </span>
                        <span class="slds-file-selector__text slds-medium-show">or Drop Files</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it seems bizarre, but you can't directly paste the code from SLDS into a component. The standout problem with what you have there is that it has an `<svg>` tag in it, which is not directly supported in a Lightning Component.

So, you could replace the `<svg>` by using something like this:

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:upload" size="small" />
```

Although, to be honest, you should really just use:

```
<lightning:fileUpload />
```

Instead of copying the file upload HTML from SLDS anyway.